# Iterate asynchronously through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, asynchronous, event-loop

I always find Python a very frustrating language, because to find a simple thing I have to dig into the whole internet.

I'm trying to iterate a list of dictionaries asynchronously. Is that possible? I have the following code:

```
def get_report(url, type):
  res = request.post(url, data=dict(type))
  return res.json()

def get_reports(data):
  reports = []
  for item in data:
     report = get_report(item['url'], item['type'])
  return report

get_reports([
  { 'url': 'https://example.com', 'type': 'text' }
  // ....
])
```

and I want to make it asynchronous. I know, it's not simple (AT ALL). I'm trying to do the following:

```
async def get_reports(data):
  reports = []
  async for item in data:
     report = await get_report(item['url'], item['type'])
  return report
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at threading? Do you want multiple requests to go out at once?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I came from a Node.js background, where those things are by default asynchronous (and concurrent).

Comment: Isn't async in Python used for writing concurrent programs as well?

Comment: Recent versions of python add asynchronous tools, but those aren't central to the language.  It wasn't written from the groundup for async work.

Comment: Which fullstack package are you using? ie what creates the `request`?  `flask`?

Comment: Which modules are you importing?  Which python version? (some async features were added in 3.7).  So what happens when you try that `async` code?